# Помогите перевести код с C++ на JS. Пытались, но не срабатывается for в for'е

Tags: javascript, c++, циклы

Код на c++:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
 {
  int num ; int temp;
    for(int i = 1;i <= 100;++i){
        temp = i; num = 0;
        while(temp)
        {
num = num * 10 + (temp%10);
temp /= 10;
        }
 if(num == i) cout << i << endl;
    }
}
```

Попытка перевести на JS:

```js
let num = 0;
let temp;
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; ++i) {
  temp = i;
  while (temp) {
    num = num * 10 + (temp % 10);
    temp /= 10;
  }
  if (num == i) {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

Как for в for'е, так и While тут не срабатывает..

Comment: Вы считаете, что неважно, где находится `num=0;`, - снаружи или внутри цикла? ---------- > тут не срабатывает Что это значит? Что должно "срабатывать"?

Comment: в `c++` `temp /= 10;` это деление на цело и в результате целое число. В js - получается дробное число, которое не равно `0`. Достаточно сделать отброс дробной части, например с помощью `Math.trunc`

Comment: Оо,  Math.trunc сработало. Огромное спасибо. Я сам вообще на С++, и с кем имаюсь тоже больше по С++. Не знали, что делит с остаком.

Comment: Сработает и | 0

Comment: Это куда писать надо будет? Вместо temp/=10 писать temp|0? Или как...

Comment: Я указал в ответе

Comment: Вижу, простите. Первый раз пользуюсь данным сайтом.. А данное округлять будет любое число? Даже если 999.86 все равно округлить сможет? А то мало ли..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам никто не говорил что эти языки родственные и перевод в данном случае будет выглядеть так, и не забудьте про округление пожалуйста.( Я использую |0 обычно)

```js
let num;
let temp;
for (let i = 1; i <= 100; ++i) {
  temp = i;
  num = 0;
  while (temp) {
    num = num * 10 + (temp % 10);
    temp = (temp / 10) | 0; // не забываем про округление
  }
  if (num == i) console.log(i);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

#include

using namespace std;

int main()

{

Int L;

Float uzunlik;
Cout<<”uzunlik qiymatini kiriting”; cin>>L;

Uzunlik=L/100;

Cout<<”uzunlik=”<

Return 0;

}

Comment: 1 - код не рабочий, 2 - код не имеет никакого отношения к вопросу.